# python3 why does my comparison change the formatting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, comparison, string-comparison

I have 1 time that is formatted like this

```
start_time  01:13:05
```

I have a second time that looks like it

```
Current time  01:13:10
```

When I calculating the difference, it produces the correct answer but chops a zero off

code:

```
new_start_time = datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M:%S')
new_current_time = datetime.strptime(str(current_time), '%H:%M:%S')
elapsed_time = new_current_time - new_start_time
```

produces:

```
elapsed time  0:00:10
```

The 10 is correct but what happened to the zero? How do I hack it back on? I need it.

Comment: `elapsed_time` is a `datetime.timedelta` object, how are you formatting it to get your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
elapsed_split = str(elapsed_time).split(":")
elapsed_time = int(elapsed_split[0]).zfill(2) + elapsed_split[1:]
```

Comment: I know you're on the right track, but I can't find split. Is it depreciated? Google pulls up only very old URL  -> AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I edited the answer converting the variable to str, sorry

Comment: I apologize but I don't see what is different.

Comment: str(elapsed_time).split(":") elapsed_time is converted to str and then split